# When would you use server-side scripting over a SPA in web application development?

Tags: reactjs, spring, web, web-applications, single-page-application

I am a big fan of SPAs. The clear separation of front-end and back-end just makes a lot of sense to me. Development in frameworks based on server-side scripting (e.g. Vaadin, JSP, ...) always felt a bit "hacky". Sure, in the case of Vaadin you get a lot of work done quickly and can limit yourself to a single programming language. But other than the "ease" of development for smaller projects, what are reasons for picking server-side scripting approaches over a SPA?

Answer (score 1):

SSR is good for SEO. SPAs does not perform well when it comes to search engine optimisation. Though there are some libraries that help you overcome this drawback of SPAs, but it is bit "hacky".